# Cluster markers in Android keeping infowindow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Currently, I have google maps, and a number of custom image markers on it, and when clicked they show a custom info window a user can interact with. Because of the number of items, I want to cluster them, but all examples I've looked at, I can't work out how to keep the title, snippet and icon of each.

Below is the code, and I need to somehow work out how to cluster them till a certain zoom level as they are all in a small space.

```
public class ParkMap extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

//set map zoom on load
private LatLngBounds zoo = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(51.346629, -0.316823), new LatLng(51.351078, -0.316393));

//animal points around the park
static final LatLng entrance = new LatLng(51.349448, -0.314918);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_park_map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(zoo.getCenter(), 16));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);


        //sets the markers for animals
        Marker centrance = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(entrance));

    }
}
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
//info window shows here
}
```

}

I've removed all but one marker position and adding the marker as they're all the same just a different position, but there are around 40 markers.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried to use `android-maps-utils` [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)?

Comment: I have, but I couldn't seem to figure getting an infowindow to work as it should